# How to save an Object containing List of Objects in MongoDB collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Java Class named Status and it consists of 3 fields namely : String Email, String Status, ArrayList(Comment) commentList. Comment is another Java class consisting of 2 String field. I have worked with MySQL and i know how i could save this Status object in database table. Now i am learning MongoDB and i need this Status object to store in my db collection. How do i do it? As of now i have tried the following and failed to store the Status object. Can anyone please help me with it?
I have tried the following :

```
public static MongoClient getMongoConnection() {
    MongoClient mongo = null;
    try {
        mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mongo;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
MongoClient mongo = getMongoConnection();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("myTestdatabase");
        DBCollection myReviews = db.getCollection("myStatus");
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();

    List<Object> commentList = new BasicDBList();
    commentList.add(new Comment("Looks like a nice status", "email@gmail.com"));
    commentList.add(new Comment("This is a nice status", "email@gmail.com"));


    Status status = new Status();
    status.setStatus("This is my new Status");
    status.setEmail("email@gmail.com");


    obj.put("status", status.getStatus());
    obj.put("email", status.getEmail());
    obj.put("comments", commentList);
        myReviews.insert(obj);
```

}

I get this error.

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.Comment.
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.Comment.

Comment: MongoDB can only handle  Bson types. Instead of adding comment object to dbList. Create a dbobject out of each comment and add them to list just like you did for your status object.

Answer (score 0):

mongo.getDB is depreciated.  Use the below to create your DB.  Make sure you import bson as well.

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);        
MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("myDB"); 
MongoCollection items = db.getCollection("myCollection");

Document document = new Document();  // Create the document to be inserted to the DB
document.put("First Name", "John");
document.put("Last Name", "Smith");

items.insertOne(document);  // Insert document to DB
```

Comment: No this didnt work. Still the same exception. org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.Comment